# How do I reduce phantomjs memory usage

Tags: phantomjs

I run on my VPS a script that generates organic visitors from google. The script generates .sh files and the traffic starts once the file is opened.

I4M NOT A DEVELOPPER AS I BOUGHT THE SCRIPT

but their support don't answer lately and I need a way to reduce the memory usage (it"s 98%)

Thanks everyone

Comment: 98% of your computer's RAM? What's the usage in gigabytes?

Comment: the problem occured on my computer and VPS. The computer have 16 GB RAM. I need to explain how the script works: It's proxies based , once a proxy finishes it's work another one comes to replace it. Now for each proxy a phantomjs command is found on task manager and I need to terminate them manualy

Comment: The script is using 16gb of memory? Well, obviously without seeing it it's impossible to say for sure what's going on. Sharing the code would probably violate an agreement with the author. If memory usage increases over time, it sounds like a standard resource leak.

Comment: I've bought the developer version of it with the source code, I can share it with you privetly if it's possible.

Comment: I probably wouldn't be able to diagnose it considering I don't even know what PhantomJS is used for, and haven't used Javascript in a few months. You'll almost definitely need to get ahold of the original author and have them fix it. Contacting them will probably be easier than trying to get help here since this question is off topic for the site. It'll probably be closed in a bit.

Comment: @hideo Ask Vitallium: [https://github.com/Vitallium](https://github.com/Vitallium)

Comment: It seems that adding auto-exit function after the end of what script is doing would do the trick for you. I can look into it if you like.

Comment: Vaviloff, how can I reach you ?

Comment: Just in case anyone sees this and it might help: Judging from the comments im 99.99% sure that the issue is that the author of the script was too careless and forgot to close the browser after one proxy was done. Letting the instance just sit there while the next is being opened, and the next, and the next, and the next. I speak from experience as I made this same mistake when I first used phantom in a script myself. No full answer from me because not enough details from OP about pretty much anything. (And YES, this WILL end up using 16GB of RAM. Potentially even way more than that.)